# Eliminar enlaces que contienen una palabra específica con regex

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Han inyectado enlaces en mi base de datos, necesito limpiar todos los enlaces que contengan la palabra "replica" con una expresión regular.

El texto de prueba que estoy queriendo limpiar es:

**EDITO:**

```
PRIMER TEXTO.<a href="http://www.ulster.ac.uk/nexu.php"><img title="fake watches china" src="images/restore.jpg" alt="" border="0"></a> 
SEGUNDO TEXTO.<a href="http://www.biogas-info.co.uk/Stall.php"><img title="replica watches" src="images/restore.jpg" alt="" border="0"></a> 
TERCER TEXTO.

CUARTO TEXTO.
<a href="http://www.biogas-info.co.uk/Stall.php"><img title="replica watches" src="images/restore.jpg" alt="" border="0"></a> 
QUINTO TEXTO.
<a style="text-decoration:none" href="http://rolexreplicachina.com"><font color="#00000">replica watches</font></a>SEXTO TEXTO.
<a href="http://rolexreplicachina.com" style="text-decoration:none"><font color="#00000">replica watches</font></a> SEPTIMO TEXTO
```

Necesitaría una regla que haga match en:

```
<a *replica*</a>
  
Osea:

<a CualquierCosaQueContengaLaPalabraReplicaCualquierOtraCosa</a>
```

Tengo lo siguiente **EDITADO:**

```
(<a.*replica.*<\/a>)+
```

Pero el resultado que estoy obteniendo falla, al considerar erróneamente una etiqueta de cierre `</a>` que no corresponde.
Debería mostrar el primer enlace (que no debería coincidir con el patrón) y también el texto `SEGUNDO TEXTO`

O sea que la regla debería contemplar desde `<a` hasta el "inmediatamente siguiente" `</a>` y que a su vez tenga dentro de esas dos coincidencias la palabra `replica`

**DEMO:** [demo en regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Trspel/4)

Answer (score 0):

Esque eliminas las comillas en el patrón [^"] y replica aparece despues de las comillas. Puedes probar

```
/<a[^>]*\bhref\s*=\s*".*replica.*?<\/a>/
```

Con lo que las comillas se incluyen en el patrón
**EDITO**
Si en esa expresión el .* antes de réplica se lo como todo, hay que olverlo perezoso con un ?

```
preg_replace('/<a[^>]*\bhref\s*=\s*".*?replica.*?<\/a>/msi
```

Creo que esto puede ir. Si no habría que complicar el código, quizás pudieras ir mirando de romper la cadena en enlaces individuales y luego recomponer con el texto limpio. Es una idea.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Juan por tu respuesta, se arregló en parte con tu aporte, pero sigo con problemas ya que también me elimina texto entre dos enlaces, mira: [enlace](https://regex101.com/r/Trspel/2)

Answer (score 0):

Sería algo así

```
/(<a.*replica.*<\/a>)+/g
```

. cualquier caracter y * cero o más de los precedentes

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Pepe, pero también me produce la eliminación del texto entre dos enlaces, mira: [enlace](https://regex101.com/r/Trspel/2)

Comment: Para clarificar pon tu resultado esperado y tu entrada(completa). Supongo que quieres eliminar enlaces contenidos en otro texto más grande.

Comment: Exactamente, es un texto en una base de datos, y en un campo a veces aparecen más de un enlace conteniendo esa palabra. Por ejemplo en el texto `ESTE TEXTO DEBE DEJARLO <a href="http://www.ulster.ac.uk/nexu.php"><img title="fake watches china" src="images/restore.jpg" alt="" border="0"></a>ESTE TEXTO TAMBIEN DEBE DEJARLO<a href="http://www.biogas-info.co.uk/Stall.php"><img title="replica watches" src="images/restore.jpg" alt="" border="0"></a> Y ESTE OTRO TEXTO TAMBIEN DEBE DEJARLO` debo eliminar todos los enlaces, pero dejar el texto que está sin los enlaces.

Comment: Usa una función remplazar por regex (dependiendo de la bd varía el nombre) que remplace el texto de la expresión regular `(<a.*replica.*<\/a>)` por cadena vacía, globalmente. La expresión regular por si misma no sustituye solo es una regla para buscar coincidencias.

Comment: Por ejemplo en MySQL 8+ `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(campo,'(<a.*replica.*<\/a>)',''); `

Comment: Hola Pepe, sigo con el problema, también me está borrando desde el comienzo de un enlace anterior que no coincide con el patrón; Entonces en la regla tendría que incluir que dentro del primer `<a`   y del último `</a>` no exista otro `</a>` Por favor fijate en: [enlace](https://regex101.com/r/Trspel/3)